# Creating a file with variable name in c++

Tags: c++, file

so I want to create a file but the name of it will be dependent on the user input e.g. if the user types "shrek" the file must be named "shrek.txt". Thats what I came up with but it doesn't work.

```
int main(){
    ofstream file;

    string name = "abc";

    file.open(name + ".txt");
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Your program does create an empty file called "abc.txt", as you instructed it to do.

Comment: i doesnt on my pc

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work on my PC"? It fails to compile? It crashes? it doesn't create a file?

Comment: it doesnt compile and doesnt create the file

Comment: What compiler are you using? On what OS?

Comment: If it doesn't compile, what compile errors do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using an old C++ standard. If that's the case, `fstream::open` won't accept a `std::string`, only a C string (`char*`). You can use `c_str` in your string to obtain a `const char*` that will be accepted:

```
int main(){
    ofstream file;

    string name = "abc";
    string file_name = name + ".txt";
    file.open(file_name.c_str()); // <- here
    file.close();
}
```

However, it's recommendable to switch to a more modern standard, as your code actually works for C++11 and newer.

Comment: how can I switch it

Comment: To be corrected, `std::basic_string::c_str()` doesn't really cast anything, it just returns a `const char*` null terminated C string that happens to point to the underlying storage of the string (in C++11) or that `str[i] == str.c_str()[i]` for every valid index in the string.

Comment: @low_ratio Dev-C++ is a very old and obsolete IDE, and AFAIK it ships an outrageously  ancient version of GCC that doesn't even default on C++11 yet. You may have a better experience if you switch to Visual Studio Community - given that you are just picking up C++, it's really worth it to focus on modern C++.

Comment: thanks. I was also wondering what other IDEs would you recommend

Comment: Thanks, @mcilloni, I'll edit to be more accurate

Comment: Just the other day we had some poor soul trying to use a version of Dev C++ so old that it came bundled with GCC3.4 from way back in 2005-or-so. Needless to say, a lot of our recommendations just didn't work for them. If you like the feel of DevC++, consider using [this up-to-date version](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/releases). Otherwise, I usually push new programmers toward a [Community edition of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/). It usually works right out of the box so you can get right into learning C++.

Comment: @low_ratio I am not an IDE guy, and I usually prefer to use a plain editor like Neovim (maybe with a bit of code completion) and a CLI. On Linux I really like using Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ extension, but on Windows it requires you to install several gigabytes of Visual Studio Build tools, so you might as well install the full Visual Studio and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the libraries required? In this case #include fstream. Does the same issue happens to another complier? Check that out. I attempted this myself and your code surely works. Attempt to use my code which I confirm works and see if you have any issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>      
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string name;
    cin>> name;
    ofstream file(name +".txt");
    file.close();
    
}
```

Comment: I am using c++ 11. thats what was causing the problem

Comment: @low_ratio C++11 doesn't have problems with your code. Earlier C++ version does though.